# JqGrid: Use $.ajax() instead of editurl

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the JqGrid, but I need a little more control over what happens when the "Save" button is clicked in a form edit/insert. Ideally, I'd like to use my own $.ajax() call to send all form data to the server instead of relying on the grid to do it using an editurl.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid support `ajaxEditOptions`, `editData` options `serializeEditData`, `errorTextFormat`, `afterSubmit` and `onclickSubmit` events and many other form edit [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) and [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events). The features allows you to make practically full dynamical customization of the `editurl` (see `onclickSubmit`), to send additional parameters (see `editData`) or suppressing sending of some standard parameters to the server (see `serializeEditData`). With respect of `ajaxEditOptions` you can change any from the `jQuery.ajax` parameter (use `contentType: "application/json"` or HTTP PUT instead of POST). The data which will be send to the server can be serialized with respect of your custom function (see `serializeEditData`) and the response can be decoded with your function (see `afterSubmit` or `errorTextFormat` in case of server error). You can make some highlighting or other animation effects after the add of new row (see `afterComplete`). I can continue...

I would recommend you try to use the features which I listed above instead of overwriting standard mechanisms of the form editing.

If you describe more exactly in your question **what you want implement** I (or other) could try to explain you which jqGrid features you can use for that.